# Como salvar uma página html em java

Tags: javascript, java, jquery, html5, pdf

Estou com um projeto o qual preciso fazer um relatório para cada código. E salva-lo no disco no formato de PDF. Após gerar o relatório,  não sei como passar a página (gerada) para o Servlet e assim salvar em PDF.

Consegui fazer o envio do html para o servlet, agora preciso saber como converter as tags (html) para que o java possa interpreta-las e transformar em PDF.

Servlet

```
    /*
     * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
     * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
     * and open the template in the editor.
     */
    package br.com.drz.paraopeba.servlets;

    import com.itextpdf.text.Document;
    import com.itextpdf.text.html.simpleparser.HTMLWorker;
    import com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfWriter;
    import java.io.File;
    import java.io.FileOutputStream;
    import java.io.IOException;
    import java.io.OutputStream;
    import java.io.PrintWriter;
    import java.io.StringReader;
    import javax.servlet.ServletException;
    import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
    import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
    import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
    import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

    /**
     *
     * @author douglas
     */
    @WebServlet(name = "salvarPDF", urlPatterns = {"/salvarPDF"})
    public class salvarPDF extends HttpServlet {

        private static final String SAVE_DIR = "relatorios";

        /**
         * Processes requests for both HTTP <code>GET</code> and <code>POST</code>
         * methods.
         *
         * @param request servlet request
         * @param response servlet response
         * @throws ServletException if a servlet-specific error occurs
         * @throws IOException if an I/O error occurs
         */
        protected void processRequest(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
                throws ServletException, IOException {
            response.setContentType("text/html;charset=UTF-8");
            try (PrintWriter out = response.getWriter()) {

            }
        }

        // <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="HttpServlet methods. Click on the + sign on the left to edit the code.">
        /**
         * Handles the HTTP <code>GET</code> method.
         *
         * @param request servlet request
         * @param response servlet response
         * @throws ServletException if a servlet-specific error occurs
         * @throws IOException if an I/O error occurs
         */
        @Override
        protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
                throws ServletException, IOException {



            processRequest(request, response);
        }

        /**
         * Handles the HTTP <code>POST</code> method.
         *
         * @param request servlet request
         * @param response servlet response
         * @throws ServletException if a servlet-specific error occurs
         * @throws IOException if an I/O error occurs
         */
        @Override
        protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {

            String  html = request.getParameter("conteudo");


            try {

                String appPath = request.getServletContext().getRealPath("");
                String savePath = appPath  + SAVE_DIR + File.separator;

                OutputStream file = new FileOutputStream(new File(savePath + "teste.pdf"));
                Document document = new Document();
                PdfWriter.getInstance(document, file);
                document.open();
                HTMLWorker htmlWorker = new HTMLWorker(document);
                htmlWorker.parse(new StringReader(html));
                document.close();
                file.close();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            processRequest(request, response);
        }


        /**
         * Returns a short description of the servlet.
         *
         * @return a String containing servlet description
         */
        @Override
        public String getServletInfo() {
            return "Short description";
        }// </editor-fold>

    }
```

Comment: Pode ser mais especifico, sobre o para cada código? É necessário a utilização de javascript?

Comment: Sim, a parte de geração de conteúdo está tudo ok, será exibido a página HTML o relatório para ser impresso / salvo. Agora não sei com faço para enviar esta página para o servlet e transforma-lo em PDF.

Comment: Javascript para Java não sei como, porém apenas em java, existe algumas libs para parsear o código html e gerar um pdf. Uma delas é o iText.

Comment: A parte de Javascript / jQuery está pronta, preciso saber como pegar este resultado (ou a página atual que foi gerada) e enviá-la para JAVA e transformar-lo em PDF.
Essa é um dos relatórios, preciso realizar mais 3000 outros.

Comment: @DouglasGaldino consegui enviar o conteúdo da página (tags) via $.ajax, agora preciso saber se é possível fazer a converter e salvar em PDF.

Comment: Cuspir o HTML no browser e o usuário gerar o PDF não é uma solução? Se não é, sugiro que voce olhe um framework de geração de relatório como Jasper, ferramenta iReports ou algo do tipo...

Comment: @Thiesen lamentávelmente não, pois imagina uma 'pequeno' relatório de 3.400 itens. =)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Uma opção para geração de PDF seria gerar um relatório mesmo utilizando [iReports](http://community.jaspersoft.com/project/ireport-designer) ou [Jasper](http://community.jaspersoft.com/project/jasperreports-library).

Se isso não é uma opção, voce pode se aventurar em bibliotecas que convertem HTML para PDF, alguns casos [aqui](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2685395/a-java-library-for-converting-xml-html-to-pdf)

Não recomendo muito a utilização desse tipo de biblioteca, já que normalmente a geração do PDF não é muito consistente. Cada uma dessas bibliotecas interpreta o CSS de um jeito diferente, e alguns casos, nem interpreta. O resultado final normalmente fica grosseiro e feio.

Se o seu HTML for simples o suficiente, talvez voce possa minimizar esses problemas.

Comment: Bom, consegui dar mais um passo e consegui abrir o arquivo, recebo o html, mas ele não está encontrando o caminho da aceitando os caminhos das imagens. Atualizei os códigos.

Comment: Acho que voce vai ter que fazer o download dessas imagens e colocar em um caminha local, fazer o parse do html para esse caminho local, e aí sim fazer a geracao do PDF pelo HTMLWorker. Quase lá!